# Data is not being added to Firebase Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

This is the error I get when I try and add data, @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.7.0): WebChannelConnection RPC. When I read about it, people said that it means that there is an issue between the application and the database, which is what is happening in my case

I tried downgrading and upgrading the library and still came up with the same error. I'm not sure if this is the root of my problem but regardless, I cannot add any data to my database.

This is my function to add the data:

```
addProduct = async (activeI,brand,productId,qua,expyea) => {
    try{
        await addDoc(collection(db, 'tasks') ,{
            brandName: brand,
            activeIngredient: activeI,
            created: Timestamp.now(),
            proId:productId,
            quantity:qua,
            // expiryMonth:expmon,
            expiryYear:expyea
        })
        alert("added")
      }
     catch (err) {
        alert("Please Fill in All Fields")
    }
  }
```

This is the full error:

> [2023-12-28T11:19:26.325Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.7.0): WebChannelConnection RPC 'Write' stream 0x45cffe61 transport errored: {"defaultPrevented": false, "g": {"A": true, "J": null, "T": [Circular], "g": {"A": 3, "Aa": 600000, "B": null, "C": 0, "D": "gsessionid", "G": false, "Ga": "jxDdqL3iKu1tDB1vRPlPg6tiBTwIVTzNvXfLVqy8Rv0", "H": 0, "I": [O], "Ia": -1, "J": true, "Ja": 12, "Ka": true, "L": "nt9JDa2NaUIccddfKv4dfA", "M": 45000, "Ma": [yd], "N": true, "P": true, "R": false, "T": 361, "W": [Object], "X": 0, "Y": 77536, "aa": "https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Write/channel", "ca": true, "da": 4, "ea": true, "eb": 5000, "fb": false, "g": null, "gb": false, "h": [fe], "hb": 2, "i": [td], "ib": 1, "j": [Array], "kb": 10000, "l": [Tb], "m": null, "o": null, "pa": null, "qa": [Object], "ra": undefined, "s": null, "sa": "", "ta": undefined, "u": null, "ua": 8, "v": null, "ya": undefined, "za": [O]}, "h": {"database": "projects/pharmacy-app-a81d8/databases/(default)"}, "i": {"g": [Object], "h": 4, "src": [Circular]}, "j": {"g": [Circular]}, "l": "https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Write/channel", "o": undefined, "s": false, "v": true}, "status": 1, "target": {"A": true, "J": null, "T": [Circular], "g": {"A": 3, "Aa": 600000, "B": null, "C": 0, "D": "gsessionid", "G": false, "Ga": "jxDdqL3iKu1tDB1vRPlPg6tiBTwIVTzNvXfLVqy8Rv0", "H": 0, "I": [O], "Ia": -1, "J": true, "Ja": 12, "Ka": true, "L": "nt9JDa2NaUIccddfKv4dfA", "M": 45000, "Ma": [yd], "N": true, "P": true, "R": false, "T": 361, "W": [Object], "X": 0, "Y": 77536, "aa": "https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Write/channel", "ca": true, "da": 4, "ea": true, "eb": 5000, "fb": false, "g": null, "gb": false, "h": [fe], "hb": 2, "i": [td], "ib": 1, "j": [Array], "kb": 10000, "l": [Tb], "m": null, "o": null, "pa": null, "qa": [Object], "ra": undefined, "s": null, "sa": "", "ta": undefined, "u": null, "ua": 8, "v": null, "ya": undefined, "za": [O]}, "h": {"database": "projects/pharmacy-app-a81d8/databases/(default)"}, "i": {"g": [Object], "h": 4, "src": [Circular]}, "j": {"g": [Circular]}, "l": "https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Write/channel", "o": undefined, "s": false, "v": true}, "type": "c"}

Comment: How are you calling `addProduct()` ? Is it possible that you are not properly `await`ing it or handling the returned Promise correctly?

Comment: Do you call `addProduct` from react native directly, or through a backend server? If so, what is the environment it is deployed to?

Comment: @GregFenton this is how I called the function, I don't think there is any problem with how I called it since it worked perfectly on web 

<TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.scanbutton}
          onPress={() => this.addProduct(active, bran,prodId,quan,expYea)}
        >
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Done</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/6993#issuecomment-1435695556)(solution) and [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/6993#issuecomment-1438671835)(explanation), the issue could be related to a proxy between your app and firestore servers.

So try enabling long polling to see if it solves your issue for now:

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { initializeFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = initializeFirestore(app, {
  experimentalForceLongPolling: true
})
```

Comment: It still didn't solve the issue, should I install any packages